# Appending image ID to image file name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

by using xp_dirtree and by doing some work around am able to get all the images into a temporary table and now i have to insert the same into main table with identity column ImageID and at the same time i have to append the same imageid to starting of the image file name added with '_' original file name

am using a query something like to insert main table

```
insert into tblImage(ImagePath)
SELECT fullpath + '\' + subdirectory 
FROM #Directory ORDER BY fullpath,subdirectory;
```

currently am using loops in c# dot net to do so .... as inserting one image getting image id (scope_identity) and appending it to the file name.

but it taking large time as number of images increases.

Is there any better way to accomplish this in sql server only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming after the insert, the data in tblImage will look something like this?

```
ImageID    ImagePath
1          somefilename.jpg
2          someotherfilename.jpg
```

The identity value will only be available after the insert, so you can do a bulk update after the initial bulk insert. The identity value is not available during an insert.

```
UPDATE tblImage SET
    ImagePage = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ImageId) + ImagePath
WHERE (You'll have to specify a where clause to limit the update to the newly created records)
```

or you can add a 3rd column to tblImage

```
UPDATE tblImage SET
    NewFileName = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ImageId) + '_' + ImagePath
WHERE NewFileName IS NULL
```

if you need to change the filename on disk, I can think of two possible solutions.

The first and quickest to implement, would be to use xp_cmdshell execute the rename statements. (this assumes ImagePage has the original filename, and NewFileName has the new filename.)

```
DECLARE @Cmd        NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @Cmd = @Cmd + 'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''rename "' + ImagePath + '" "' + NewFileName + '"''
'
FROM tblImage

EXEC (@CMD);
```

To use xp_cmdshell, you need to enable if first, as it's disabled by default.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

The second option to rename files on disk would be to setup a FileTable in SQL Server that points to the directory containing the files you want to rename. Then the renaming of the file becomes a simple update statement.

You can read more about FileTables [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144(v=sql.110).aspx)

There's also a couple of really comprehensive walkthroughs about setting up FileTables.

Hope that helps.